# preg_replace Не заменяет знак доллара

Tags: php

```
preg_replace('/\$/', 'UAH', '10$');
```

В данной строке замены не происходит. Способы из гугла не помогают. Как заменить $ в строке?

Comment: все работает https://paiza.io/projects/tp_bZBRWTRBAwTp663CHtw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для простой замены подстроки предпочтительнее использовать функцию [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php):

```
str_replace('$', 'UAH', '10$');
```

Если очень хочется использовать регулярные выражения, заменить знак доллара можно так:

```
preg_replace('/[$]/', 'UAH', '10$');
```

Comment: вы проверяли код из вопроса ?

Comment: @teran, мистика какая-то=) Когда проверял, не работало.